# Parsing with derivatives - intermediate nodes

Tags: parsing, racket, derivative

I am looking at the code for parsing with derivatives (derp-latest [here](http://www.ucombinator.org/projects/parsing/) ) and I'm struggling a bit. I am interested in natural CFGs and I can get it to work building parsed trees, but the code produces no interdemiate node names, only a tree structure. It also omits  The [Haskell implementation](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/haskell/pwd.html) does produce intermediate node names, so I guess it should be possible but I don't understand haskell code.

I have got it to work more or less by explicitly adding node names to the ∘, but I'm not sure this is correct, I also don't have a solution for ★, which is why I commented it out in D.

```
(define-lazy-struct δ {lang})
(define-lazy-struct ∪ {this that})
(define-lazy-struct ∘ {name left right})
(define-lazy-struct ★ {lang})
(define-lazy-struct → {lang reduce})

; Derivative:
(define/memoize (D c p)
  #:order ([p #:eq] [c #:equal])
  (match p
    [(∅)           (∅)]
    [(ε _)         (∅)]
    [(δ _)         (∅)]
    [(token p?)    (cond
                     [(equal? p? c) (ε (set c))] ; [(p? c) (ε (set c))]
                     [else   (∅)])]
    
    [(∪ p1 p2)     (∪ (D c p1) 
                      (D c p2))]
    ; [(★ p1)        (∘ (D c p1) p)]
    [(→ p1 f)      (→ (D c p1) f)]
    [(∘ name p1 p2)     (∪ (∘ name (δ p1) (D c p2))
                           (∘ name (D c p1) p2))]))

(define/fix (parse-null p)
  #:bottom (set)
  (match p
    [(ε S)        S] ; 
    [(∅)          (set)]
    [(δ p)        (parse-null p)]
    [(token _)    (set)]
    [(★ _)        (set '())]
    [(∪ p1 p2)    (set-union (parse-null p1) (parse-null p2))]
    [(∘ name p1 p2)    (for*/set ([t1 (parse-null p1)]
                                  [t2 (parse-null p2)])
                         (cons name (cons t1 t2)))]
    [(→ p1 f)     (for/set ([t (parse-null p1)])
                    (f t))]))
```

given the grammar:

```
(define N (∪ (∘ "N" (token 'man) (ε (set '())))
             (∘ "N" (token 'girl) (ε (set '())))
             ))

(define Det (∪ (∘ "Det" (token 'the) (ε (set '())))
           (∘ "Det" (token 'a) (ε (set '())))
           ))

(define V (∪ (token 'kill)
             (token 'hit)
             ))

(define NP (∪ (∘ "NP" Det N)
          (∘ "NP" N (ε (set '())))))

(define VP (∘ "VP" V NP))

(parse '(kill girl girl) VP)

> (set '("VP" kill "NP" ("Det" the) "N" girl))
```

Which looks ok.

Similarly, with the grammar:

```
(define NP2 (∘ "NP2" NP (ε (set '()))))

(parse '(girl) NP2)
```

I get the expected intermediate nodes:

```
(set '("NP2" ("NP" ("N" girl))))
```

My questions are:

1. Is this approach correct or is there a better way?
2. If it's correct, what's the best way of fixing ★?